# Выравнивание блоков на вкладке активности профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Подозрительно не выравнены блоки по высоте на вкладке активности профиля:

[image: блоки]

Дополнительные вопросы вызывает расположение шестерёнок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном, подобного рода ошибки происходят из-за длинны строк перевода. Попробовал решить проблему изменением строки «Следующая привилегия» на «След. привилегия».

Comment: Кстати, даже на enSO наблюдается небольшая разница по высоте между упомянутых блоков. Пара или тройка пикселей.